# Displaying error message in form

Tags: php

I want to display error message or alert message after checking the condition.

here is my code

```
    session_start();

    $plan = @$_GET['plan'];
    $plan = +$plan; 
    include('connect.php');

            If (isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
            $CompanyName = $_POST['CompanyName'];

            $CompanyEmail = $_POST['CompanyEmail'];
            $CompanyContact = $_POST['CompanyContact'];
            $CompanyAddress = $_POST['CompanyAddress']; 

            $RegistrationType = $_POST['RegistrationType'];
            $Plans = $_POST['plan'];
            $Status = "Active";
    $query1 = "select count(CompanyEmail) from ApplicationRegister where CompanyEmail = '$CompanyEmail'" ;
    $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die ("ERROR: " . mysql_error());
    //$result1 = mysql_result($query1, 0, 0);
    //echo $result1;
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))

                {
                    //$companyemail = $row['CompanyEmail'];
                    //if($companyemail != '' || $companyemail!= 'NULL')
                    //{
                        if($row['count(CompanyEmail)'] > 0)
                        {


        echo "This E-mail id is already registered ";
    }
    else
    {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ApplicationRegister(CompanyName, CompanyEmail, CompanyContact, CompanyAddress, RegistrationType, ApplicationPlan, ApplicationStatus, CreatedDate) VALUES ('$CompanyName', '$CompanyEmail', '$CompanyContact', '$CompanyAddress', '$RegistrationType', '$Plans', '$Status', NOW() )";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$id = mysql_insert_id(); 

$_SESSION['application_id'] = $id;


//if(isset($plan == "trail"))
if($plan == "trail")
{

header("Location: userRegister.php?id=$id");
exit();
}
else
{
    header("Location : PaymentGateway.php");
    exit();
}


    }
    }
                }

?>
```

and after this i have placed my html form

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td><h2><br />
                  Application Registration</h2>
                  <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"  onsubmit="return Validate();">
                <input type="hidden" name="plan" value="<?php echo $plan ?>"/>
    Company Name: 
        <input type="text" name="CompanyName" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
    Company E-mail : 
    <input type="text" name="CompanyEmail" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
     Company Contact <input type="text" name="CompanyContact" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
     Company Address: <input type="text" name="CompanyAddress" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br /><br />
    Select Your Registration Type : <br /><br />
Trail: <input type="radio" name="RegistrationType" value="Trail" /><br />
                                     Paid<input type="radio" name="RegistrationType" value="Paid" /><br /><br />

     <input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" value="1"/> 
     <input type="submit" value="REGISTER" name="submit" />



</form> 


    </td>
              </tr>

            </table>
```

When the user entered companyemail is already exists it should display the alert message just below the company email field in the form. But now its displaying in the starting of the page. I dont know what to use and how to use. Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$msg = "";
if($row['count(CompanyEmail)'] > 0)
                    {


    $msg = "This E-mail id is already registered ";
}
```

and HTML

```
<input type="text" name="CompanyEmail" style="width:230px; height:20px;" /><br />
<?php echo $msg; ?>
```

Comment: Miqdad Ali:   thank you very much. This is what i wanted. but how to make the font red in this.

Comment: $msg = "<font color='red'>This E-mail id is already registered</font> ";

Answer (score 0):

This query will return only one record. So its not need to use while loop

```
$query1 = "select count(CompanyEmail) from ApplicationRegister where CompanyEmail = '$CompanyEmail'" ;
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die ("ERROR: " . mysql_error());
```

Try this,

```
    $query1 = "select count(CompanyEmail) from ApplicationRegister where CompanyEmail = '$CompanyEmail'" ;
    $result1 = mysql_query($query1);     
    $row = mysql_ferch_array($result1); 
 if($row['count(CompanyEmail)'] > 0){
     error message 
}else{ 
 insert uery 
 }
```